# Arrayformula circular dependency Problem in Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas, circular-dependency

I wanna use this Arrayformula for a row (get the data from that row, and have the input also in it).

`=ARRAYFORMULA(IF((LEN($C1:$C100)>240),IMPORTDATA(CONCATENATE("tinyurl.com/api-create.php?" & $C1),"")))`

If the link is longer than 240 char. > to make it with tiny URL instead. It works if I put the formula on a different row, but when I try to conditional format the whole row it doesn't work / return anything, or when I use it as arrayformula it has the #REF - circular dependency error.

Is there a way to solve this (apply it to the whole row, take the date from that row and return the output on it also).

[image: see] < it works on B - when applied for A, but not on row C for C

Thanks. (I couldn't link tiny url, but you can see it full in pic)

Comment: You cannot use & apply the formula on the same C column as it will cause a `#REF!` error `Array result was not expanded because it would overwrite data in C2` (this occurred after fixing `circular dependency` error on the Spreadsheet by turning `On` the [Iterative settings](https://workspaceupdates.googleblog.com/2016/12/new-iterative-calculation-settings-and.html). Is your goal to auto update all URLs on the C column based on the conditions you have on your formula? If not, could you show a sample expected result (a screenshot/sample shared sheet) you'd like to get for better understanding?

Comment: Yes, I want to use and apply it in the same row. I've tried with turning on Iterative settings too, but it doesn't work (gives me the overwrite error, and then obviously if I clear the cell so it doesn't overwrite data, it doesn't have where to take the value from) . I'm wandering though why doesn't it work with conditional format custom formula either. My point is that I don't want to add another helping row. But do it all in the same one.

Comment: That looks impossible just by using the pre-loaded functions on Google Sheet. You would need to use a custom script for this to be achieved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Suggestion:

You can try this sample script below that will add a `Custom Menu` on your spreadsheet file. Just copy & paste the script to your sheet as a [bound script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound#creating_a_bound_script):

### Script:

Copy the script from [here](https://codeshare.io/RbzBzj)

> Note: Codes that contains tiny URL API, [see here for more info](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313621/blacklist-the-use-of-common-link-shorteners-in-posts), can't be posted directly on here. Thus, I have temporarily shared the sample script from this free code sharing [site](https://codeshare.io/), which will expire after 24 hours

### Sample Demonstration:

> After saving the custom script, you will have these options:

[image]

> Option 1 will produce the same result as to your original formula. The option 2 will ignore the URLs below 240 characters.

***Sample:***

[image]

***Result:***

[image]

> If you select `Tiny URL ver.2`, only the URLs with more than 240 characters will be changed and the rest of the URLs remains the same instead of being replaced with `FALSE`

[image]

Comment: works like a charm! thank you. I'm not that familiar with google scripts yet but I'll look more into it